# How to perform a fast cut zero edge in python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, image-processing

I have a binary image size of `256x256x256`, where the foreground region is located in a small region, and I have a lot of zero margins. I want to cut zero edges by finding the minimum and maximum coordinate of points that has pixel non-zero in images. It worked but it spends time-consuming. I post my code and could you tell me how we can make it faster?

For the image size of `256x256x256`, it takes about 0.13024640083312988 seconds. This is the code and you can run online at https://repl.it/repls/AnxiousExoticBackup

```
import numpy as np
import time

def cut_edge(image, keep_margin):
    '''
    function that cuts zero edge
    '''
    D, H, W = image.shape
    D_s, D_e = 0, D - 1
    H_s, H_e = 0, H - 1
    W_s, W_e = 0, W - 1

    while D_s < D:
        if image[D_s].sum() != 0:
            break
        D_s += 1
    while D_e > D_s:
        if image[D_e].sum() != 0:
            break
        D_e -= 1
    while H_s < H:
        if image[:, H_s].sum() != 0:
            break
        H_s += 1
    while H_e > H_s:
        if image[:, H_e].sum() != 0:
            break
        H_e -= 1
    while W_s < W:
        if image[:, :, W_s].sum() != 0:
            break
        W_s += 1
    while W_e > W_s:
        if image[:, :, W_e].sum() != 0:
            break
        W_e -= 1

    if keep_margin != 0:
        D_s = max(0, D_s - keep_margin)
        D_e = min(D - 1, D_e + keep_margin)
        H_s = max(0, H_s - keep_margin)
        H_e = min(H - 1, H_e + keep_margin)
        W_s = max(0, W_s - keep_margin)
        W_e = min(W - 1, W_e + keep_margin)

    return int(D_s), int(D_e)+1, int(H_s), int(H_e)+1, int(W_s), int(W_e)+1

image = np.zeros ((256,256,256),dtype=np.float32)
ones_D_min, ones_D_max, ones_H_min, ones_H_max,ones_W_min, ones_W_max= 100,200, 90,150, 60,200
image[ones_D_min: ones_D_max,ones_H_min:ones_H_max, ones_W_min:ones_W_max]=1
t0=time.time()
ones_D_min_result, ones_D_max_result, ones_H_min_result, ones_H_max_result, ones_W_min_result, ones_W_max_result= cut_edge(image,0)
t1=time.time()
print ('Time consuming ', t1-t0)
print (ones_D_min, ones_D_max, ones_H_min, ones_H_max,ones_W_min, ones_W_max)
print (ones_D_min_result, ones_D_max_result, ones_H_min_result, ones_H_max_result, ones_W_min_result, ones_W_max_result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that if you `sum` over an axis of your 3D array, then the value will still be 0 where there is no 1 in the row (or column or third dimension) depending on which `axis` parameter. Then by using `any` in one of the two other directions and `np.argwhere` you will get the index where there is at least one 1 in the other axis. Using `min` and `max` will give the value you are looking for. Here is the function:

```
def cut_edge_2(image, keep_margin):
    im_sum0 = (image.sum(0) !=0)
    im_sum1 = (image.sum(1) !=0)
    ones_D = np.argwhere(im_sum1.any(1))
    ones_H = np.argwhere(im_sum0.any(1))
    ones_W = np.argwhere(im_sum0.any(0))
    if keep_margin != 0:
        D, H, W = image.shape
        return (max( 0, ones_D.min() - keep_margin), min(D, ones_D.max() + keep_margin+1), 
                max( 0, ones_H.min() - keep_margin), min(H, ones_H.max() + keep_margin+1),
                max( 0, ones_W.min() - keep_margin), min(W, ones_W.max() + keep_margin+1))
    return (ones_D.min(), ones_D.max() +1, 
            ones_H.min(), ones_H.max() +1,           
            ones_W.min(), ones_W.max() +1)
```

You get the same result than with your function:

```
print (cut_edge(image,0))
#(100, 200, 90, 150, 60, 200)
print (cut_edge_2(image,0))
#(100, 200, 90, 150, 60, 200)

print (cut_edge(image,60))
#(40, 256, 30, 210, 0, 256)
print (cut_edge_2(image,60))
#(40, 256, 30, 210, 0, 256)
```

and some `timeit`:

```
%timeit cut_edge(image,0)
#93 ms ± 7.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit cut_edge_2(image,0)
#25.3 ms ± 8.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit cut_edge_2(image,1)
#26.2 ms ± 4.73 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit cut_edge(image,1)
#95.4 ms ± 6.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

It is faster.

Comment: Perfect!. Let I check in my computer

Comment: T: I found one bug. the result is not correct with the setting. Let check it at https://repl.it/repls/AnxiousExoticBackup

Comment: @John indeed, it was a bad copy and paste. I fixed it in the answer. In the `min`, it was always `D` and not `H` then `W` as it was supposed to for each direction. Sorry for that

Answer (score 3):

Your function can be improved significantly using numpy's built-in functions:

```
def cut_edge(image, keep_margin):
    '''
    function that cuts zero edge
    '''

    #Calculate sum along each axis
    D_sum = np.sum(image, axis=(1,2)) #0
    H_sum = np.sum(image, axis=(0,2)) #1
    W_sum = np.sum(image, axis=(0,1)) #2

    #Find the non-zero values
    W_nz = np.nonzero(W_sum)[0]
    H_nz = np.nonzero(H_sum)[0]
    D_nz = np.nonzero(D_sum)[0]

    #Take the first and last entries for start and end
    D_s = D_nz[0]
    D_e = D_nz[-1]
    H_s = H_nz[0]
    H_e = H_nz[-1]
    W_s = W_nz[0]
    W_e = W_nz[-1]


    if keep_margin != 0:
        D_s = max(0, D_s - keep_margin)
        D_e = min(D - 1, D_e + keep_margin)
        H_s = max(0, H_s - keep_margin)
        H_e = min(H - 1, H_e + keep_margin)
        W_s = max(0, W_s - keep_margin)
        W_e = min(W - 1, W_e + keep_margin)

    return D_s, D_e+1, H_s, H_e+1, W_s, W_e+1
```

And the result:

```
Time consuming  0.0963144302368164
```